# How exactly does Inset work?

Tags: plotting, graphics, export

Does anybody know how exactly the `Inset` function in *Mathematica* works?

I want to show two images: one is an image from `ListPlot`, and another image is of a sphere. I inserted the second image as an inset in the first image. I managed to do it as follows:

```
Show[
  Graphics[{
    Inset[imgIn1, {0, 0.}, {0, 0}, {2, 2}], 
    Inset[imgIn2, {1.1, 0.8}, {0, 0}, 0.4]
  }],
  ImageSize -> 600
]
```

The final image looks fine in *Mathematica*. However, when I export it and view it in `gwenview`, I see that the image has shifted right, and it has a lot of white space on its left.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post a screenshot of what you see in your notebook and in gwenview.

Answer (score 2):

`Inset` is special tool to put one graphical object into another one. 
For example, you have `ListPlot` object and you need to insert there a red circle (but actually it can be anything). Therefore, you will write:

`ListPlot[Table[Sin[x],{x,0,2Pi,Pi/36}],
Epilog->Inset[Graphics[{Red,Circle[{0,0},1]},ImageSize->100],Scaled@{0.5,0.75}],
ImageSize->600]`

[image]

The scaled coordinates {0.5,0.75} defines the position of the inset relatively to outer graphics (horizontally at the middle and at the 0.75 of its height).
The `ImageSize` options will define sizes of the both inset and host. You can use additional directives of `Inset` for rotation or positioning of the inset.

The `Epilog` is a command for plotting routines which define what will be drawn above the main graphical layer.

Comment: So how does it exaplain: " image has shifted right, and it has a lot of white space on its left."

Comment: @Kuba, Ask author please :) I've explained topic by another words. However, you will obtain something like this [link](http://savepic.ru/12772473.png) if will use the Inset by the topicstarter's way. The problem probably is because he used two insets without definition of the main bachground image.